# Changing the TCP RTO value in Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, tcp

I want to alter the TCP RTO [(retransmission timeout)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6298) value for a connection, and some reading I have done suggests that I could do this, but does not reveal where and how to change it.

I have looked at the `/proc/sys/net/ipv4` variables, but none of the variables is related to RTO. I would appreciate it if someone can tell me how to alter this value.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. At the very minimum including 'ms' with the rto time gives me an error! I did get the command to work, but ss -i says otherwise. Furthermore, the 2 sysctl vars don't exist. I'm running on a 4.4 kernel

Comment: I tried on a more recent distro and had success doing `ip route replace` instead - seems the `ip route` syntax has changed a little. I was able to make the modification successfully though. Just to note, you should comment on the answer, not the question if you want to ping me - I basically saw this by accident, pure luck that it was recent :)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The reason you can't alter the RTO specifically is because it is not a static value.  Instead (except for the initial SYN, naturally) it is based on the RTT (Round Trip Time) for each connection. Actually, it is based on a smoothed version of RTT and the RTT variance with some constants thrown into the mix.  Hence, it is a dynamic, calculated value for each TCP connection, and I highly recommend [this article](http://sgros.blogspot.com/2012/02/calculating-tcp-rto.html) which goes into more detail on the calculation and RTO in general.

Also relevant is [RFC 6298](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6298) which states (among a lot of other things):

> Whenever RTO is computed, if it is less than 1 second, then the RTO
> SHOULD be rounded up to 1 second.

Does the kernel always set RTO to 1 second then? Well, with Linux you can show the current RTO values for your open connections by running the `ss -i` command:

```
State       Recv-Q Send-Q                                                  Local Address:Port     Peer Address:Port
ESTAB       0      0                                                           10.0.2.15:52861   216.58.219.46:http
     cubic rto:204 rtt:4/2 cwnd:10 send 29.2Mbps rcv_space:14600
ESTAB       0      0                                                           10.0.2.15:ssh          10.0.2.2:52586
     cubic rto:201 rtt:1.5/0.75 ato:40 cwnd:10 send 77.9Mbps rcv_space:14600
ESTAB       0      0                                                           10.0.2.15:52864   216.58.219.46:http
     cubic rto:204 rtt:4.5/4.5 cwnd:10 send 26.0Mbps rcv_space:14600
```

The above is the output from a VM which I am logged into with SSH and has a couple of connections open to google.com.  As you can see, the RTO is in fact set to 200-ish (milliseconds).  You will note that is not rounded to the 1 second value from the RFC, and you may also think that it's a little high.  That's because there are min (200 milliseconds) and max (120 seconds) bounds in play when it comes to RTO for Linux (there is a great explanation of this in the article I linked above).

So, you can't alter the RTO value directly, but for lossy networks (like wireless) you can try tweaking [F-RTO](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4138) (this may already be enabled depending on your distro).  There are actually two related options related to F-RTO that you can tweak (good summary [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20211120181310/https://whitequark.org/blog/2011/09/12/tweaking-linux-tcp-stack-for-lossy-wireless-networks/)):

```
net.ipv4.tcp_frto
net.ipv4.tcp_frto_response
```

Depending on what you are trying to optimize for, these may or may not be useful.

EDIT: following up on the ability to tweak the rto_min/max values for TCP from the comments.

You can't change the global minimum RTO for TCP (as an aside, you can do it for SCTP - those are exposed in sysctl), but the good news is that you can tweak the minimum value of the RTO on a per-route basis.  Here's my routing table on my CentOS VM:

```
ip route
10.0.2.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.2.15 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1002 
default via 10.0.2.2 dev eth0
```

I can change the rto_min value on the default route as follows:

```
ip route change default via 10.0.2.2 dev eth0 rto_min 5ms
```

And now, my routing table looks like this:

```
ip route
10.0.2.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.2.15 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1002 
default via 10.0.2.2 dev eth0  rto_min lock 5ms
```

Finally, let's initiate a connection and check out `ss -i` to see if this has been respected:

```
ss -i
State       Recv-Q Send-Q                                               Local Address:Port                                                   Peer Address:Port   
ESTAB       0      0                                                        10.0.2.15:ssh                                                        10.0.2.2:50714   
     cubic rto:201 rtt:1.5/0.75 ato:40 cwnd:10 send 77.9Mbps rcv_space:14600
ESTAB       0      0                                                        10.0.2.15:39042                                                 216.58.216.14:http    
     cubic rto:15 rtt:5/2.5 cwnd:10 send 23.4Mbps rcv_space:14600
```

Success! The rto on the HTTP connection (after the change) is 15ms, whereas the SSH connection (before the change) is 200+ as before.

I actually like this approach - it allows you to set the lower value on appropriate routes rather than globally where it might screw up other traffic.  Similarly (see the [ip man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ip)) you can tweak the initial rtt estimate and the initial rttvar for the route (used when calculating the dynamic RTO).  While it's not a complete solution in terms of tweaking, I think most of the important pieces are there.  You can't tweak the max setting, but I think that is not going to be as useful generally in any case.

Comment: Thanks @Adam C for the clarification, but you mentioned the min (200 milli)  and max ( 120sec), can I change any of these (min or max)? if yes, how?...

Comment: I believe they are constants in the code, and I am not aware of a way to set them dynamically but will dig a bit and see since I assume altering the code and compiling your own kernel is a bit much :)

Comment: Figured out how to tweak rto_min and added it and a couple of other related things in the answer :)

Comment: Why aren't there anything like `rto_max` ? How do we set a global maximum timeout ?

Comment: If you set the minimum (or accept the default) and then alter the number of retries (`net.ipv4.tcp_retries1` and `net.ipv4.tcp_retries2` or similar IIRC) allowed, I think you can get to an equivalent of an RTO maximum.